# Syslog config syntax

Tags: linux, ubuntu, logs, syslog

I have setup a syslog server to test it out and its working perfectly fine.
I want to understand what this syntax is actually doing in the rsyslog.conf file of the server that I added as guided by several experts.

Also how would I identify which logs are coming from a remote computer , since there is only one file in the /var/log folder which has some logs , how can i separate for remote host entirely in a separate folder?
The syslog isn't creating a file or folder with the hostname at all.

```
$template TmplAuth,"/var/log/%HOSTNAME%/%PROGRAMNAME%.log"
```